# Pnpm installation and review results (windows10)

Tags: node.js, pnpm, .npmrc

I write everything step by step. I read and applied all the pages on the website from start to finish (from Introduction to Advanced).

It may also be useful to appear, I'm not an expert software developer. I'm trying to be a hobby.

When I was working on an old project, I wanted to try "pnpm" again, which I had tried and failed to use before.

Using

- Os: Windows 10 x64
- Editor: WebStorm
- node: 14.15.0

Project:
The project I'm working on is the "Ionic-Angular" project. The total size of the project is "699 MB" when I use it with "npm".
Problem:
After installing "pnpm" and making the setting files, I opened the project and waited for it to install packages with the "pnpm install" command. It's over before there's any trouble. However, the total size of the project has risen to "1.11 GB".

Step by step, as for what I've done.

1. install nodejs LTS edition 14.15.0 win64
2. run PowerShell (as admin).

- npm config edit
- change all paths -> prefix, cache, tmp, userconfig, globalignorefile, globalconfig.

  list of changes .npmrc file;

  ```
  prefix=C:\Users\mhy\npm\.npm-global
  cache=C:\Users\mhy\npm\.npm-cache
  tmp=C:\Users\mhy\npm\.npm-temp
  userconfig=C:\Users\mhy\npm\.npmrc
  globalignorefile=C:\Users\mhy\npm\.npm-global\etc\npmignore
  globalconfig=C:\Users\mhy\npm\.npm-global\etc\npmrc
  store-dir=C:\Users\mhy\pnpm\.pnpm-store
  global-dir=C:\Users\mhy\pnpm\pnpm-global
  npm-path=C:\Program Files\nodejs
  ```

3. Restart Computer
4. install pnpm PowerShell

- (Invoke-WebRequest 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pnpm/self-installer/master/install.js').Content | node
  )
- pnpm creating %AppData%Romaning%\npm folder. And cut folder paste new path all files.
  (pnpm, pnpm.cmd , pnpx, pnpx.cmd move to npm-path [nodejs installation folder])
- According to the narrations on the website, I added the following paths to the ".npmrc" file.
  load .npmrc files (2 same file) and add [store-dir, global-dir, npm-path -> change for pnpm] paths

5. Open WebStorm ide and go to Settings->Language & Frameworks->node.js and NPM->Select    Package Manager, changed it manually to -> npm-path (because I moved the "pnpm,pnpm.cmd" files to this location.)
6. Testing;

- Run PowerShell and command: pnpm add @ionic/cli -E --global
  "@ionic/cli" was installed in the designated location without any problems.

7. Then I installed all the packages in "devDependencies" with the command "pnpm add -E --global" with PowerShell.
   It configure them all, it don't see any problem. Back to WebStorm ide and close PowerShell.
8. Open Project and write terminal this command "pnpm install"

- pnpm ok, no problem. Everything looks fine.

9. When I looked again at the size of the "Project" folder, I saw that it had grown too much.

- Old size 699 MB new size 1.11 GB
- only node_module folder 996 MB.

10. The size of the post-"pnpm" project folders look like this.

- project folder = 1.11 GB
- node_module folder = 996 MB
- node_module -> .pnpm (I guess virtual store folder) 437 MB
- node_module -> All other folders without .pnpm folder 642 MB
- node_module -> .ignored + .ignored_ast_types-flow, .ignored_eslint-scope .ignored_mime-types .ignoder_multicast-dns-service-types -> 244 MB
- and the "pnpm-global" and "pnpm-store" folders created as I mentioned earlier (.npmrc file);
- pnpm-global -> 269 MB
- pnpm-store -> 540 MB

  Total size project+pnpm global and store = 2 GB (windows explorer showing folder size 2gb)
  I use PowerShell and get folder size, list all folder transfer to excel column and sum folders size = 767 MB
- Old Size = 699 MB   using npm
- New Size = 767 MB   using pnpm

  I use PowerShell commands this

  $fso = new-object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject gci -Directory `| select @{l='Size'; e={$fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size}},FullName`  sort Size -Descending `| ft @{l='Size [MB]'; e={'{0:N2}    ' -f ($_.Size / 1MB)}},FullName | out-file out.txt

Actually, I think it should be like this.It will load master packages into one folder(ex: C:\pnpm-global ), and add them as symlink-junction from there when using them in other projects. But there's a note on the website for "virtual-store-dir." NOTE: the virtual store cannot be shared between several projects. Every project should have its own virtual store.

I installed "pnpm" because I targeted to reduce the project size (junction-symlink etc).

I also can't find any resources when I want to know something about "pnpm" on the internet. There's only the website, there's a very limited resource.

I don't think there's a lot of use, but I have no idea what it's going to be like when there are so many more projects i've used for 1 project.

Answer (score 0):

Testing npm and pnpm for Ionic/Angular projects, results

Using npm

1. Create new ionic+Angular blank project, total folder size = 341 MB
   Project size (without node_modules) = 573 KB
2. Steps ->

- npm install
- npm audit -> 1
- npm audit fix
- save projects and project folder new size = 408 MB
- ng build
- ng serve
- save projects and project folder new size = 481 MB

Using pnpm

1. Create new ionic+Angular blank project, and delete node_module folder.
   Project size (without node_modules) = 573 KB
2. Steps ->

- pnpm install
- pnpm audit -> 1
- pnpm not have audit fix -> manual install @angular-devkit/build-angular
- save projects and project folder new size = 375 MB
- ng build -> compiling error @ionic/angular
- delete node_module folder
- pnpm install --dev -> folder size 316 MB
- pnpm install -> folder size 375 MB
- ng build -> error ionicons
- delete project folder

Second attempt;
(working but size increase)!

- change default package manager = pnpm
- pnpm add @ionic/cli --global
- ionic start
- blank project
- but install package npm, not use pnpm
- folder size = 408 MB
- pnpm install
- folder size = 783 MB
- pnpm run build (run script ng build)
- pnpm run start (run script ng serve)
- save projects and project folder new size = 856 MB

Third attempt

- not create ionic start command,
- copy files new folder (without node_module),
- angular.json add "cli.packageManager pnpm"
- copy .npmrc file and add "shamefully-hoist=true" line
- pnpm i --shamefully-hoist
- folder size = 375 MB
- ng build
- ng serve
- folder size 448 MB

Result is for me

- If I use "npm", it will be 481 MB.
- If I use "pnpm", it will be 448 MB.
- 33 MB difference occurs in between

Like I said, I'm not an expert, I just did a test of my own and wanted to share the results.

If I'm using it wrong, can someone please tell me step by step about using this pnpm like I did?